# Code optimization in Android

Tags: android

In almost every Android tutorial I learned to add a click listener to a Button like this:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Do stuff
                    }
                });
```

But with time I learned to do like this:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
```

I know it's not a big thing, but do I gain any performance doing like this? If yes, can someone show me more examples on how to optimize my code?

Comment: I'm not big on dalvik/ART internals, but I'd be surprised if that even generates different code.

Comment: Read about "premature optimization" and why it is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid trying to be too clever with code. You gain no performance bonus here but you do add extra complexity when reading through your own code. Variable condensing hardly gives any performance gains over algorithm design.

Plus in your 2nd case, you have no reference to the button (or other views) to perform other tasks in your Activity: how would you set the text? Change the background programmatically?

The only thing worth pointing out is to reduce repeated `findViewById` calls if possible (which is why storing a View in a field is useful throughout your Activity). There's a reason why it's `findViewById` and not `getViewById`: the find implies there's a search involved in retrieving the View for you (so it is not retrieved in O(1)). So keeping a reference to a View you've already found is good if you plan to use it for other things!

In a ListView you would optimize by following the ViewHolder pattern, which is a static class that stores a reference to the View ids for the row layout to reduce repeated `findViewById` calls. [See this blog post for more info regarding ViewHolder design pattern.](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Note that RecyclerView (API 21) has the ViewHolder pattern built in and requires you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly, the differences -if any- would be inconsequential. If you want to reduce boilerplate code consider using something like ButterKnife: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/.

Comment: That library is doing the same thing behind , with more stuff, which is useless.

Comment: Reducing boilerplate code is not the same as optimising code.

Comment: Paul, it is not useless. I'd like looking at any code with dozens of findViewById calls look cleaner than code using ButterKnife. It's called boiler plate for a reason.

Comment: ci_, yes it is not the same but then again he's not really "optimizing" anything. The only thing optimized from the first snippet to the second is the amount of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't optimize that much, because is a simple task.

The OnClickListener is from View, and not from Button, so you can also do like this

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
```